# Running Docker with infile bash syntax

Tags: r, bash, docker

I need to run R in a Docker container and want to input a script from a volume I mounted using the standard infile notation, however, the file seems to be redirected to Docker, not R.

I'm using the following command:

`docker run -v /root/share:/share r-base:latest R --vanilla --quiet < /share/test.r`

How can I use the infile notation and run my R in Docker? (I need the direct output from R, so Rscript will not do.)

Comment: The way your command line shows here, it does exactly what you describe: `docker ... < /share/test.r`: feed `/share/test.r` to `docker`. (Does `/share/test.r` even exist outside the docker? Anyway, it depends on your docker image how to best feed stdin to the command inside the docker.

Comment: you could try this line `docker run -v /root/share:/share r-base:latest /bin/bash -c "R --vanilla --quiet < /share/test.r"`

Comment: @MazelTov Thats works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As @mazel-tov mentioned: try

```
docker run -v /root/share:/share r-base:latest /bin/bash -c 'R --vanilla --quiet < /share/test.r'
```

That way the redirection of stdin is done by the `bash` inside the `docker` instead of in your shell that starts the docker.